Get Image Orientation .NET MAUI
I'm trying to figure out how to get the image rotation on Android/iOS devices using .NET MAUI.  I have the following code to get the Image Width and height. NOTE: I allow the user to select an image from their device. This is the <path_to_image>.
I've got the following code working on Android devices:
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(<path_to_image>))
{
  image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
  if (image != null)
  {
    Int32 width = Convert.ToInt32(image.Width); 
    Int32 heigh = Convert.ToInt32(image.Height);
  }
}

I can use this code to determine if the image is landscape or portrait.  But now I need the Metadata information of the image to determine the Metadata orientation (similar to the following: Problem reading JPEG Metadata (Orientation)  which only works on Windows).
Thoughts?

there are numerous nuget packages that will extract EXIF data from an image

@Jason : Do you have a favorite Nuget package you like to use for this? Maybe one called ExifLibNet (nuget.org/packages/ExifLibNet)? Whichever one I choose needs to work with the latest versions of .NET MAUI as well as on Android and iOS devices. Thanks.

Android
ExifInterface Class is a class for reading and writing Exif tags in various image file formats for Android.
Let's say we have an image, and we use ExifInterface to get the orientation of this image.
    #if ANDROID
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
            // ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(inputStream);
            ori = exifInterface.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagOrientation);

    #endif

Please note that we may get the value of 0,1,2,3.., which has different meanings of direction. You may refer to the android docs for more info, ExifInterface.
iOS
For iOS, UIImage has UIImage.Orientation Property, which you may get it using the following way.
    #if IOS
        UIImage image = new UIImage(imagePath);
        var ori = image.Orientation;
        
        //Console.WriteLine(image.Orientation);
    #endif


For more info, you may also refer to the Apple;s doc, UIImageOrientation
As you can see, the above code use Conditional compilation to invoke platform code for Android and iOS.
